# Applet Optimize JVM

Tags: java, struts2, applet, jvm, aspose

I am using Aspose Slide to generate PPT (2003) in Struts 2 Web Project, As it is greedy in RAM,  we used Threads to do it in asynchronous mode, using FIFO Stack, to run threads a after one, it works fine, but regarding to the number  of users, generating a PPT could consume long time, so I am thinking to an issue to that but I am not sure, the question is:

Could I use Applet to run the PPT generation in client side? does it a good practice for that?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You certainly can generate the presentations on the client side, and for the very reason you mentioned, time consuming processes should always be done on the client if at all possible.

You may want to consider using javascript on the client to generate the file instead of an applet though, as an applet will require the user to have the java plugin installed on their system, and you would need a security certificate to sign the applet.

*Javascript* on the other hand would not require any special plugins, and would not require a security certificate, since you can generate the file data and dynamically create a link using a data URI for the user to download/launch the presentation

Comment: Thanks for your response, but note that Aspose needs 2 jars to be downloaded, I don't know how javascript could generate PPT(2003) ???, in addition to file license that client side will have it as a FileStream, for that reasons I think applet will be more convenient , on the other hand do you have any idea about generating PowerPoint with JavaScript ?

Thanks

Comment: yeah, well pptx files are really just .zip files that contain xml files. in fact if you rename a .pptx file to .zip, you can even extract it as normal. Javascript is built for handling xml, and so if you are familiar with the format, you should be able to generate the files fairly easily. i believe the format is called openxml

Comment: js zip libraries such as jszip, found at stuartk.com/jszip/ can handle zipping the files for you then all you have to do is generate the xml

Comment: yes @Aaron, but the problem is that we are using PPT not PPTX, it is a binary file not XML :(, So I think applet will be more convenient